# curl -F "data={json:'code'}" in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to access a third-party API with PHP.

Their command reference is like so:

```
curl "https://api.example.com/api/" \
  -H "Authorization: BEARER-TOKEN" \
  -F 'data={"language":"EN","latitude":12.345,"longitude":12.345}'
```

I've tried:

```
    $url = 'https://api.example.com/api/';
    $header = array(
        'Content-type: application/json',
        'Authorization: ' . $bearertoken
    );

    $fields = 'data={"language":"EN","latitude":"'.$latitude.'","longitude":"'.$longitude.'"}';

    // I've tried this too:
    $fields = array('data' => '{"language":"EN","latitude":"'.$latitude.'","longitude":"'.$longitude.'"}');

    $ch = curl_init();

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);`
```

But the server responds with a message telling me it didn't get the parameters I'm sending.  When I send the same `-F "data={}"` from a terminal I get the correct response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `Content-type: application/json`. The value of the `data` parameter is JSON, but the parameters as a whole are sent in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

You also need to URL-encode the value of the `data` parameter.

The best solution is to use `json_encode` to create the JSON value, then use an array of post fields, then `curl` will encode the fields properly.

```
$header = array(
    'Authorization: ' . $bearertoken
);
$fields = array('data' => 
    json_encode(array('language' => 'EN',
                      'longitude' => $longitude,
                      'latitude' => $latitude)));
```

Answer (score 1):

`curl -F` submits the form using `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`, following [RFC 2388](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388). You're specifically contravening that when you set the `application/json` content type.

```
$data = array('language' => 'EN', 'longitude' => $longitude, 'latitude' => $latitude);
$headers = array (
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
    "Authorization: $bearertoken",
);
$postfields = array ("data" => json_encode($data));
$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Also, if that's the actual documentation, it may be wrong. [The format for Authorization header](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/120244/72365) is `Authorization: Bearer <token>`.